# Can different configurations manage files other than web.config in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, configurationmanager

I have a project that need to be tested and deployed for many different customers and those clients sometimes have different needs.
It is an MVVC app, I use .net MVC but only for few bit and pieces, like some partial views and so on, everything else is a single page app using knockout.js.

So I have different web.config files but also I have a file that contains client side configuration, a .js file that is different for every customer.

Now if make different configurations in visual studio with configuration manager I get different web.config depending on the configuration I choose, and that is perfect.

But is there a way to have the same result for another file in the project?

like for example have a myfile.nightly.js and myfile.debug.js and so on. (those files contains configuration settings like the color of the page or the logo or the section to hide, that are proper to each different customer).

I tried this solution with prebuild events: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

but that is quite an hold post and I would like to know if there is something more actual with VS2012 for example

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on why you need different js files to begin with? What do they contain? Configuration settings, which are environment dependent, usually reside in a .config file, which is easily transformed using Xml Transform.

Comment: they are configuration settings for the client side code(javascript), I would like to have them in a structured way that is why I used a javascript object or a json data file. A .config may do to, but how do you transfer it to your javascript variables?

Comment: I have added more info in the qestion.

Comment: Have you thought about not using configuration in the javascript files, and instead build these customer specific things when the page is being generated by MVC? That way, you can keep your client configuration server side, but generate the page appropriately. Personally, that's what I'd do, I feel one of the purposes of server side generated pages is to be able to apply custom behavior, in your case depending on user/customer/etc.

Comment: I have thought a lot about that, but I have a lot of configuration variables and many need to be javascript variable because are used by javascript libraries like highchart, knockout and so on. And .net does not allow mvc code in the .js files.

Comment: You can't have razor code inside js files, but you can change the url of the js files on the page, for instance. I would at the very least try to isolate these "client side settings" on a single js file (one for each customer) and them create the link to them dynamically on page creation, on the server. In the end, this would produce the same results as what I proposed on the edit in my answer, using a custom `HttpHandler`. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature you are talking about (in the case of the web.config) is called Xml Transform. Unfortunately, Visual Studio only has support to transform web.config files automatically and nothing else.

[SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) was created to transform other xml files of your choice, but it only works for Xml files. You can configure it to transform the files on each build (via a custom msbuild task) for instance.

I'm not aware of any solutions to transform javascript files though.

EDIT:

<strike>Perhaps you could build your own `HttpHandler` class to serve the customized js file? The link to the js file on the page would point to it, and it would serve a different js file for each customer, and the switching logic would be in the server.</strike>

I still feel this is a poor solution (but I may be biased because of Web Forms), and that ideally you would generate the page with this information already set, that is, the configuration could be in the web.config file for instance, and the controller on the server side could use the settings to personalize the page.

EDIT 2:

Ok. Based on the last comments I now understand that this is *static* configuration, i.e., it is deployment specific, and does not change based on a user on the same website for instance. Considering that, I feel this should not be part of the build process, but of deployment.

I would seriously consider using a deployment tool to customize the files based on target environment. Microsoft's own [Release Management](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx) can achieve that relatively easily using the built-in workflow activities. In the release pipeline, you could pick the javascript file you want, based on any parameter you pass to the workflow.

Comment: the last one is a good solution to the original question different from the one I already tried.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark If you can share how exactly you are "switching" these js files it would help too. For instance, if these are permanent changes (for a given deployment of your site, the js is always the same) I would completely avoid using code logic to get them. It would be the responsibility of the deployment script/process to select the appropriate file. On the other hand, if on the same site instance, you need to select different files, based on users for example, then you will invariably need to go with the switching code route.

Comment: the solution I tried is in the original question in a link. is made with a prebuild event

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark Edited my answer, please take a look.